# GIT : New branch is pointing to the dev branch

Tags: git

I've cloned a branch from github and it's name is dev.
I've started using it, pulling and pushing the code changes and making sure that my local repository is up to date with remote.
I'd to start implementing a new functionality and hence created a new branch as follows:

```
/>git branch <newBranchName>
```

Branch created successfully. I've verified the commit numbers of dev and this new branch and both are same. Then I've pushed that branch to github as follows:

```
/>git push origin newBranchName
```

No issues till this moment. I've started working on this new branch and then pushed the code to github and then realised that it pushed all changes of dev branch.

```
/>git branch -vv
```

says that this new branch is pointing to dev branch. However my team mates are able to push the changes to this new branch on github.
What would have gone wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a branch isn't enough.
All that does is create the branch. It does not put you on it; you are still on dev.

You need to checkout the branch before creating any new commit:

```
git checkout newBranchName 
// commits
git push -u origin newBranchName
```

If you didn't already created the branch, a simple `git checkout -b newBranchName` would have been enough.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create and checkout a new branch immediately with `git checkout -b newBranchName`.